# Probability of rolling a die twice

Tags: probability

I have a statistics question.  Please let me know if I am on the right track.

> If you throw a die for two times, what is the probability that you will get a three on the first throw or a three on the second throw (or both).

Here's what I have so far.  I know there 6 possible outcomes each time you throw the die.  So there is a $1/6$ chance of getting a 6. Do I simply do that twice and multiply it together to determine the probability of doing it twice.  In other words would it be $1/6 \times 1/6 = 1/36$ or $2.7\%$ or do I need to include the possibility of failure.  For example, $1/6$ chance of success and $5/6$ chance of failure for each role and then add those together.  $1/6 \times 5/6 = 13.9\%$ for the first trial and then $1/6 \times 5/6 = 13.9\%$ for the second trial so together it would be $28\%$.  Please help.

Comment: The probability on throwing no sixes at all is $\frac56\frac56=\frac{25}{36}$. So the probability on at least one six is $1-\frac56\frac56=\frac{11}{36}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Laplace experiment and the set of outcomes that are positive for the event is
$$E=\{(i,j)|i=3 \lor j=3\}$$
and it is easy to see that $|E|=6+6-1=11$ ( don't count $(3,3)$ double).
And as the space of all outcomes $\Omega$ has $6^2=36$ elements You get
$$P(E)=\frac{|E|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{11}{36}.$$

Answer (score 5):

The probability of rolling a 3 on the first roll is $1/6$. Then, you don't care on what you roll on the second roll.

If you don't roll a 3 on the first roll (with probability $5/6$), then you again have a probability of rolling a 3 that is $1/6$.

So the global probability of rolling at least one $3$ is $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{6} = \frac{11}{36} \approx 30.5\%$